# Exporting raster from QGIS to use it in other programs

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, import

I am having a hard time trying to set a raster in a way that I can use it in AutoCAD map, for example. So these are the steps that I am doing:

Below is the image from the google satellite with the vectors of the lanes (in UTM Zone 23S, as is the project)

[image]

I then exported the map as image, and as you can see in the print below, when I put the output image it in QGIS, it landed in the right place.

[image]

Well, with the little I know about projections, I thought I had successfully exported the image so I could use it in AutoCAD map. Then I just went and exported the vectors as dxf, in UTM zone 23s as well, but when I tried to import both the raster and new dxf they weren't in the same place at all!

To better explain all my steps, I'm inserting here what I'm doing when importing the data to AutoCAD map.

First I'm converting the vector to dxf in QGIS in Sirgas 2000 UTM 23S

[image]

Then I'm opening the dxf file in AutoCAD map and assigning the coordinate system (Sirgas 2000 UTM 23S)

[image]

And lastly I'm importing the raster created when I imported as image in QGIS

[image]

Here the result of the journey, the vector in a place and the raster far away from it

[image]

Could someone help me to understand what did I do wrong and how could I achieve the results that I'm seeking?

Comment: Is Autocad picking up the CRSs properly in `Geolocation/Location Panel/Edit Location/...` If not, you might try setting them.

Comment: Also, your CAD-drawing must be in the "correct" place, too, since CAD itself doesn't know about projections.

Comment: I added some other information in the main post. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: QGIS reprojects on the fly. Check if your qgis "VIAS entities" layer is also in Sirgas 2000 UTM 23S, check if the export to dxf is also in Sirgas 2000 UTM 23S. check if your QGIS project crs also uses Sirgas 2000 UTM 23S.

Comment: I just checked and everything seems fine, all layers in SIRGAS 2000 UTM zone 23S. To verify which one (the exported dxf or the raster) was in the wrong place I compared the two of them in autocad map with some other image that I have that I know for sure is inserted correct, and it seems that the problem is with the raster. But I don't really know if the steps that I described above to export an image are the proper way to do it, if someone could confirm that to me or send me some references that I could read.

Comment: In the CAD, wich layer is in the right coordinates? DXF export may be done in Imperial units, in that case you must edit the DXF header or just open the DXF in AutoCAD, change the units of the drawing, save it and import it again.